# SS32x25.ocx - License information for this component not found

Tags: vb6, ocx

when i compile the vb application i got the err

License information for this component not found. You do not have an appropriate license to use this functionality in the design environment

Please can anyone help me..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem after testing an applications install. The component registration gets set to the the user version of the control, you have to go into VB6 and set the path for the component back to the ocx that has design time permissions by going to Projects-Components